# Swapping Creatures in Troops

Tags: kemet

Regarding the Creatures in troops:

May a troop with a creature have its creature replaced with a creature not currently on the board?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rulebook doesn't say anything about recalling creatures, but you can't recall single units either, only a whole group and only after a battle. I guess it's safe to assume that it's not possible to recall a creature and put another one in the same group.

The only trick I see to achieve this is to move with the creature you want to remove from the group, split the group and take one unit with you. Go into a battle and call that unit back (or have it killed) and with the next recruitment put it back into the original group with a different creature. (Assuming the remains of the original groups are in your city.)

I think this solution may be too complicated to be actually worth to play though.